# MissingMethodException calling a method with generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, missingmethodexception

I have a library containing a class with two methods (and some others that aren't relevant):

```
public T Foo<T>()
{
    // Real version does some other things, but this is the gist.
    return (T)this.Foo();
}

public object Foo()
{
    // Do stuff and return something.
}
```

So far so good.  This library compiles.

Yet when calling `.Foo<string>()` I get a `MissingMethodException`.  What could be causing this?  Everything compiles fine.

For reference the `Foo` without the generic is the legacy method, I am introducing the generic version to help with casting etc.

Comment: Sounds like a project didn't build or old binaries were used at runtime (while the compiler used fresh binaries).

Comment: You usually get `MissingMethodException` when the DLL being used at runtime is different than the DLL you compiled against.

Comment: Exactly please clean your solution and rebuild your whole project

Comment: I executed your code, and I got different error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz Right. Because of that error the project probably did not build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the MissingMethodException is due to old dlls.  However, once you fix that, this still won't work.  You can't implicit cast an object to a string. At runtime, your call `.Foo<string>()` will call `(String)Foo()`, where `Foo` is of type `Object`.  This will basically never work unless the T you provide is already `object`.

[Read more about type conversions here, including an explanation of narrowing versus widening casting.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98bbex99%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

What is it you are trying to do with this piece of code?  If you expect to always be using `.Foo<string>()` or a subset of a few types then you could just define explicit casts for them instead.

Comment: You mean "unless the value you provide is already of type `string`". And in many cases, you *do* know which type you are expecting, but old (non-generic) code can only return `object`, and then this construct is perfectly fine to wrap such code. Of course the cast can fail at runtime, but that's another matter. It would be exceedingly clumsy to have to provide `FooString`, `FooInt32`, etcetera.

Comment: Turned out to be old DLLs that I missed due to a complexity of the build system.

Actual use case is `.ExecuteScalar<T>()` where you do typically know the type you expect from the database.